# Custom ILog interface doesn't register

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, ilogger

I created a custom interface `ICustomLog` to use with additional parameter and it doesn't register

```
public interface ICustomLogger : ILogger
{
    void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, int? OrderId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter);
}

public interface ICustomLogger<out TCategoryName> : ICustomLogger
{
}

public class UserController : BaseController<UserController>
{
    private readonly IUsersClient _usersClient;
         
    public UserController(ICustomLogger<UserController> logger, IUsersClient usersClient) : base(logger)
    {
        _usersClient = usersClient;
    }
}

public class BaseController<TCategoryName> : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly ICustomLogger<TCategoryName> _logger;

    public BaseController(ICustomLogger<TCategoryName> logger)
    {
        _logger =  logger;
    }
}
```

I have the implementation of the above interface. But it throws a dependency error.

Tried adding dependency like below after `services.AddLogging` call.

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICustomLogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Getting the error while an exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[MyProject.Controllers.UserController]' to type 'Myproj.Logging.Client.ICustomLogger`1[MyProject.Controllers.UserController]'.
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> xceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context

Is that not possible to create a custom `ILog` interface or anything wrong with the way I try to register it?

Comment: But standard `Logger` does not implement your custom `ICustomLogger`, is not it? So, if you want custom interface, you need to provide implementation which implements this interface.

Comment: Could you pls share the code about how and where do you inject the `Logger<UserController>`?

Comment: @Rena Updated the question with injection

Comment: The exception you show is not a dependency exception, it is an InvalidCastException. Which means the conversion of an instance of one type to another type is not supported.  Like @Rena has answered you need to make a class that implements the ICustomLogger interface

Answer (score 1):

You extend the `ILogger` interface, but the `Logger` class implements the `ILogger` instead of the `ICustomLogger<>`, so you need custom a class to implement the `ICustomLogger<>`:

```
public interface ICustomLogger<out TCategoryName> : ICustomLogger
{

}
public class CustomLogger<TCategoryName> : ICustomLogger<TCategoryName>
{
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        //do your stuff...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        //do your stuff...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, int? OrderId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Then register the service like below:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICustomLogger<>), typeof(CustomLogger<>));
```

Suggest you can read [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) about how to implement a custom ILogger in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I do have the implementation like mentioned, but not added here. I get while calling this

Comment: Hi @SobDev, so you need register the interface with your implementation instead of `Logger`.